# In tensorflow, randomly (sub)sample k entries from a tensor along 0-axis

Tags: python, tensorflow

Given a tensor of `rank>=1` `T`, I would like to randomly sample `k` entries from it, uniformly, along the 0-axis.

EDIT: **The sampling should be part of the computation graph as a lazy operation and should output different random entries every time it is called.**

For instance, given `T` of rank `2`:

```
T = tf.constant( \
     [[1,1,1,1,1],
      [2,2,2,2,2],
      [3,3,3,3,3],
      ....
      [99,99,99,99,99],
      [100,100,100,100,100]] \
     )
```

With `k=3`, a possible output would be:

```
#output = \
#   [[34,34,34,34,34],
#    [6,6,6,6,6],
#    [72,72,72,72,72]]
```

How can this be achieved in tensorflow?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can use a [random shuffle](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/random/shuffle) on an array of indices:

**Take the first `sample_num` indices, and use them to pick slices of your input.**

```
idxs = tf.range(tf.shape(inputs)[0])
ridxs = tf.random.shuffle(idxs)[:sample_num]
rinput = tf.gather(inputs, ridxs)
```

Comment: Just a note to others that this samples from rinput `with replacement`.

Comment: @iyop45 On the contrary, this is actually sampling _without_ replacement. Maybe you mixed the definitions? https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/parker/sampling/repl.htm